# Send some working params to doc or save to docs db while making copy of a doc using drive api

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-drive-api

1. I have some app script in my public doc, another user makes copy of
   that doc(from another account, but public) using DRIVE api.

   So, while making a doc, I want to store some params into doc's
   database or at least to script content or someway that doc can know
   that value, is it possible?
2. Also, He is gives permissions while making a copy of the doc, and
   when running doc's menu items(added by script), he again needs to
   give permissions to authorize the script.

   Can that be taken while making a copy itself?

Answer (score 0):

#### Setting Document-Specific Parameters in a New Document

> I want to store some params into doc's database or at least to script content or someway that doc can know that value...

You can accomplish this, but it requires that you use a script to create the document copy. While creating the copy, this script would also create an entry in a shared spreadsheet, with the ID of the new document and any parameters for that document.

The `onOpen()` trigger function would then set document-specific values *once*, the first time the document is opened. If the parameters have not been set yet, the script would read the shared data, find its parameters (again, based on document ID), then store them in its ScriptDb (and, presumably, set text within the document using them).

#### Permission vs Authorization

These are two separate concepts, and you cannot combine them in one operation.

Permission - the owner or an editor of a document can give permission for other users to view or edit that document.

Authorization - the owner of an account may authorize a script to perform actions on their behalf. Since some of these actions can have negative consequences (like deleting all files on Drive, or sending spam emails), each authorization decision is up to the account owner.